# sudo command to move file

Tags: macos, sudo

Hello wonderful people.

I'm having a problem when following this tutorial to make a program that once worked on a mac work again after the upgrade.

http://bit.ly/1RkmdBA

However i'm not allowed to move anything over to lib folder. Im getting a circle with a line in it. Even while i'm holding the option key,and yes i'm the administrator.

The next step the writer suggested is to use sudo command. Im not so savy with code. Can someone tell me the exact command line.

Answer (score 5):

If you would prefer to move from one location to another:

```
sudo mv ~/initial/file/location ~/destination/location
```

if you you would rather copy instead:

```
sudo cp ~/initial/file/location ~/destination/location
```

Comment: so sudo cp ~/initial/file/location ~/destination/location Contents/Resources/osx/libsndfile.1.dylib.~/usr/local

Comment: the cp command will copy, but of course replace the locations with your actual location. The first being the file you want to move and the second being the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You simply add the sudo command to the beginning of another command, and it runs the command as root (it will prompt for your password first). For example, of you want to run this as root:

```
mv this-file /usr/lib/
```

Then you would change it to:

```
sudo mv this-file /usr/lib/
```